# Do you need to have at least 1 Insight to level up?

Tags: bloodborne

I know that when you receive your first Insight you are given access to the level up NPC in the Hunter's Dream. If you ever go back down to 0 Insight do you lose the ability to level up again?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No you don't. You are correct in that you need 1 insight to awaken the doll, but if you go below 1 insight, the doll will remain awake for you to level up.

Comment: It should be noted that the doll will appear back in her lifeless doll form if you leave and come back to the Hunter's Dream with 0 Insight. But you will still be able to level up. So no Insight means no time wasted talking.